# Is the given function continuous and differentiable?

Tags: functions, continuity

The function $f:R\rightarrow R$ is defined as:

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
 & \text{ $3x^{2}$ } ; x\in Q \\ 
 & \text{ $-5x^{2}$ } ; x \notin Q
\end{cases}$

---

How to check its continuity and differentiability at $x\in Q$ and $x\in R$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is continuous at all those points where      $3x^2 =-5x^2$.

If this equation has a repeated root then the function is differentiable also at that point.

In your case the function is differentiable at $0$ only

Comment: What is the meaning of "If this equation has a repeated root then the function is differentiable also at that point" ?

Comment: you will get an equation when you equate both the branches of the function.